# how to use OR condition inside mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to use OR condition in my query but I don't why its not working as I know in mongodb to use OR condition we have to write like this `$or`

As I made my own custom id as `projectId` and i know even mongodb creates its own id as `_id`

my query follow like this

```
const getProjectById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let task = await Project.findOne({$or:{ projectId: id,_id:id}},
    }).populate("assignee");
  
};
```

but its not working

as i am trying to fetch data by both `_id` and my custom id i.e `projectId`

so here is my same data which is

```
{
      "_id": "6145b0c7331a5a4634640f27",
      "projectId": "b0jyt9gvktpl6936",
      "projectName": "Gravity",
      "projectTag": [],
      "projectDescription": "Testing",
      "taskStatus": "notStarted",
      "assignee": null,
      "createdAt": "2021-09-18T09:26:31.801Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-09-18T09:26:31.801Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: You must give us 1 sample document, we cant know what type is your _id in your database or the projectId, also what type/possible types, is the id variable on the driver. Your code to work if we assume that _id is ObjectId in the database, then projectId should be also ObjectId in the database, and you should add in both ObjectId function. If this is not the case then you must check the type of the id and deside what to do.

Comment: hi @Takis_ i have added sample document from my database

Answer (score 0):

```
const getProjectById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let task = await Project.findOne({$or:[ {projectId: id},{_id:id}]}).populate("assignee");
  
};
```

Comment: Hi i tried your code but i can only get data by `_id` its not working with my `projectId`

Comment: add this `var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;` and then replace `ObjectId(id)` with `id`

Comment: you mean like this ?? `$or: [{ projectId: ObjectId(id) }, { _id: ObjectId(id) }],` ?

Comment: yeah exactly   and import `var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;`

Comment: ya but still i cant find entry with `projectId` but if i am changing my query like this `let task = await Project.findOne({projectId:id}).populate("assignee");` i can get my projectID data

Comment: now does your or working ?

Comment: hi when I am calling with `projectId` I am getting the output but when I am calling with `_id` its showing me error `"Cannot read property 'assignee' of null"` where as same data I can fetched with `projectId`

Comment: so its related from populated `assignee` , means couldn't poulate this 
add new and `{$and:[{$or:[]},{assignee:{$ne:null}}]}`

Comment: still not working :(